# ESLINT error messages

Tags: eslint, sap-web-ide

I am trying to use extern libraries on my SAPUI5 project and follow tutorials https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/30/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-modules-in-sapui5/.
For example, I include lodash as you can see on the image:
[image]

On the image, you can see, that the sap web ide complains about third library.
How to avoid the complaint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [**`/* eslint-disable */`**](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) at the top of your target file:

```js
/* eslint-disable */
/**
 * ...
 */
;(function(){function n(n)...
```